# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'

Tags: python, list

I tried to calculate element-wise dividing for two list:

```
outCount = [0,2,1,3]
PR_old = [0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]
inSum = 0
for j in range(len(outCount)):
    if outCount[j] == 0:
        continue
    inSum += PR_old[j]/outCount[j]
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'
```

Comment: which python version are you using, any reason for indenting the for loop after `inSum`

Comment: Your code has an indentation error, but it doesn't look like it should be dividing a float by a list.  Are you sure this is exactly how the code looks on your end?

Comment: I would expect the error message in the title if you somehow forgot the index of `outcount`, eg `inSum += PR_old[j]/outCount`. But you should've got an `IndentationError: unexpected indent`.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the incorrect indentation of the `for` loop, your code is fine. It should be like this:

```
outCount = [0,2,1,3]
PR_old = [0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]
inSum = 0
for j in range(len(outCount)):
    if outCount[j] == 0:
        continue
    inSum += PR_old[j]/outCount[j]

print inSum
```

However, there are more Pythonic ways to do this. You don't really need that index variable `j`. You can iterate over both lists simultaneously using `zip()`:

```
inSum = 0
for u, v in zip(PR_old, outCount):
    if v:
        inSum += u / v
```

Or doing essentially the same thing in a generator expression and using the built-in `sum()` function to perform the addition:

```
inSum = sum(u / v for u, v in zip(PR_old, outCount) if v)
```

FWIW, the final value of `inSum` is 0.458333333333

(Code tested on Python 2.6.6)

Comment: Thank you so much but I still get a message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'

Comment: @JingtianZhang: You should not get that error with any of the code samples I posted above. Exactly how are you running this code? Are you executing a script that contains the code at the command line prompt? It will help us if you verify that the code you pasted into your question is **exactly** equal to the code in your script. And it will be very helpful if you include the full traceback of the error message. In other words, _everything_ from the word `Traceback` onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your obvious indentation error, I can't reproduce your problem.  Specifically:

```
2>>> outCount = [0,2,1,3]
2>>> PR_old = [0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]
2>>> inSum = 0
2>>> for j in range(len(outCount)):
2...         if outCount[j] == 0:
2...             continue
2...         inSum += PR_old[j]/outCount[j]
2... 
2>>> print(inSum)
0.458333333333
```

(the `2` in front of the prompts is just to show I'm using Python 2, but it doesn't matter, it would work the same in Python 3).

Please copy and paste this code (editing the prompts away of course) into a Python interactive interpreter, and show us where, exactly, in this code you show us, you get the error you report.